# Optimal way of approaching and coding multiple classes

Tags: c#

I have multiple classes that interact with each other and I got them to work and its diplaying properly but I cant help but feel that theres an optimal, cleaner and maybe even simpler way of coding this. Function is simple that it displays Product Name, Duration till Sold and Cost.

```
public class Item
    {    
    private string name;
    private int duration;
    private int cost

    public Item(string n, int d, double c)
            {
                Name = n;
                Duration = d;
                Cost = c;
            }
    }
```

Second class:

```
class Inventory
{

   private List<Item> item = new List<item>();

   public void AddItem(Item p) // Add item
            {
                item.Add(p);
            }

   public Item this[int i]
        {
            get
            {
               return item[i];
            }
            set
            {
               item[i] = value;
            }
        }
}
```

In my Form.cs I got this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            {
                var myInventory = new Inventory();
                var i1 = new Item("iPod", 200, 9);
                var i2 = new Item("Samsung", 700, 5);
                var i3 = new Item("Nokia", 100, 17);
                var i4 = new Item("Motorolla", 50, 50);

                myInventory.AddItem(i1);
                myInventory.AddItem(i2);
                myInventory.AddItem(i3);
                myInventory.AddItem(i4);
                lstProduct.Items.Add(myInventory[0]); // Add items into listbox via indexing
                lstProduct.Items.Add(myInventory[1]);
                lstProduct.Items.Add(myInventory[2]);
                lstProduct.Items.Add(myInventory[3]);

            }
```

Completely new to programming so Im still learning. Im mainly concerned with my Form.cs and the way I coded it but I welcome any feedback/suggestions if you have a better idea on how to code the other classes I made.

Thanks !

Comment: `public Item(string n, double a, int d)` That's just plain terrible. How would anyone using this code should know what does `n`, `a` and `d` stand for?

Comment: It's great you want to learn how to write better code. However, this question is too broad for Stackoverflow. Questions about code design usually belong to [softwareengineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com).

Comment: My mistake, Im not sure why I've put n, a and d but I fixed it to match up with the variables first letters so its easier to comprehend

Comment: No, don't use single letters as argument names. Use meaningful names.

Comment: I see, Ive always thought using initials makes the code look simpler but I'll keep this in mind. thanks

Comment: You can also do this: `class Inventory : List<Item> { }`. That's an easy way to make a hard-coded list.

Comment: @Enigmativity I take it you don't agree with Mr. Lippert on [this one...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt)

Comment: @ZoharPeled - No, I agree wholeheartedly. I'm just not sure if the OP is building a _mechanism_ or a _business object_?

Answer (score 1):

Here's your code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myInventory = new Inventory();

            var i1 = new Item{name = "iPod", cost = 200,duration = 9};
            var i2 = new Item{name = "Samsung",cost = 700,duration = 5};
            var i3 = new Item{name = "Nokia", cost = 100, duration = 17};
            var i4 = new Item{name = "Motorolla",cost = 50, duration = 50};

            myInventory.InventoryItems.Add(i1);
            myInventory.InventoryItems.Add(i2);
            myInventory.InventoryItems.Add(i3);
            myInventory.InventoryItems.Add(i4);
            foreach (var inventoryItem in myInventory.InventoryItems)
            {
                lstProduct.Items.Add(inventoryItem)
            }
        }
    }
}



public class Item
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int duration { get; set; }
    public int cost { get; set; }

}

class Inventory
{
    public List<Item> InventoryItems { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use public (auto) property, instead of just private field, if you'd like to access it later.

```
// for class Item
public string Name { get; private set; }
public int Duration { get; private set; }
public int Cost { get; private set; }

// for class Inventory
public List<Item> Items { get; private set; } = new List<Item>();
```

Don't abbreviate variable name. Make it easy to read.

For plural items, end your variable name with "**s**"

Override ToString() so that you can display the object instance easily.

```
// For Class Item
public override string ToString()
{
   return $"Name={Name}, Duration={Duration}, Cost={Cost}";
}

// For Inventory Item
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Items);
}
```

Use loop to iterate

```
// in Load event handler
foreach(var item in myInventory.Items)
{
    lstProduct.Items.Add(item);
}
```